# How to render React Component into itself, in a recursive way

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component say, List Component. List component can render items 
through component ListItem. Which can be easily achieved with something like below

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItem from '../list-item/list-item';

class List extends React.Component {

  renderListItems() {
    return this.props.items.map(item => <ListItem item={item} />)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="list">{this.renderListItems()}</div>
    )
  }

}
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
class ListItem extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="list-item">Name: {this.props.item.name}</div>
    )
  }

}
```

Now, in this scenario if list items can have parent children within them i.e. one list item can further render more list items how can I render ListItem component from within itself. Following is the rendering tree I am looking for and also the state of my data

```
List
 - ListItem
  - ListItem
  - ListItem
 - ListItem
 - ListItem
```

**Edit**

I think right structure will be something like this

```
List
 - ListItem
  - List
    - ListItem
    - ListItem
 - ListItem
 - ListItem
```

But it will ofcourse create a circular dependency between List and ListItem components, will that be a problem?

Comment: When I try to do what you want the page crash (of course infinite loop render will crash the page). And why you want to do that??

Comment: does your item have item.children if it has children? Why not test for that and call renderListItems() again from within the List component?

Comment: What is your data structure like? How do you know if you want to render on current level or do you want to render nested values?

Comment: @James Gentes I am actually thinking of it, but it will create a circular dependency, do you think it will be a problem?

Comment: It would only be circular if items.children always had .length > 0

Comment: Have you tried doing it, and did you encounter an error? Here is a fiddle demonstrating a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/87959/ (I suspect that your real question is about dependencies between files, and my answer to that as well is: try it and ask about any errors you encounter).

Comment: I was thinking about this exact same scenario.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should abstract your rendering logic into a separate method, which you can call recursively from the "render" method:

```
import List from 'somewhere';

class RecursiveItems extends React.PureComponent {
  constructListItem = (item) => {
    if (item.nestedItems) {
      return (
        <List key={item.key}>
          {item.nestedItems.map(this.constructListItem)}
        </List>
      )
    } else {
      return <ListItem key={item.key} item={item} />
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { listItems } = this.props

    return (
      <List>
        {listItems.map(this.constructListItem)}
      </List>
    )
  }
}

export default RecursiveItems
```

Completely untested code but it should give the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Using functional components:

```
//List.js
import React from 'react';

import ListItem from '../your_path/ListItem';

export default function List({items}) {
  return(
    <div className="list">
    {
      items.map(item => {
        if(item.name){
          return <ListItem item={item} />
        }
        return <List items={item} /> 
      })
    }
    </div>
  );
}


//ListItem.js: 
import React from 'react';
export default function ListItem({item}){
  return (
    <div className="list-item">Name: {item.name}</div>
  )
}
```

Didn't test, but I think this should work..

Answer (score 0):

Tested. 
Did call it recursively inside component's render.

```
import React from "react";
import { isItemComponent } from "../utils/utils";

const SubMenuModified = ({
      SubMenuComponent,
      ItemComponent,
      data,
      ...others
    }) => {
      return (
        <SubMenuComponent
          key={`SubMenuComponent${data.id}`}
          title={<span>{data.name}</span>}
          {...others}
        >
          {data.list.map(info => {
            if (isItemComponent(info)) {
              return <ItemComponent key={info.id}>{info.name}</ItemComponent>;
            } else {
              return (
                <SubMenuModified
                  SubMenuComponent={SubMenuComponent}
                  ItemComponent={ItemComponent}
                  key={`SubMenuComponent${info.id}`}
                  data={info}
                  {...others}
                />
              );
            }
          })}
        </SubMenuComponent>
      );
    };

    export default SubMenuModified;
```

Answer (score -6):

The recursion is cleaner in this way

```
const Asterics= ({i}) => [
  <b>*</b>,
  i>0 && <RAsterics i={i-1}/>
]
const RAsterics = (props)=><Asterics {...props}/>

export default Asterics
```

Comment: I have no idea what I'm reading here or what's going on with your code.